# retrieve list local group policy PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, active-directory, policy, group

As per the title how I can retrieve a list of local group policy? I already use gpresult but I only need the Applied Group Policy Objects list there is a way to filter only that part and not the rest?
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
gpresult.exe /X 'c:\temp\gpresult.xml'
(Select-Xml -Path 'C:\temp\gpresult.xml' -Namespace @{e="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Rsop"} -XPath "//e:GPO").Node.Name
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion mate, did you recon that it will be possible to use this script as a script block inside a invoke function for query on remote server